# Add Local .osm xml File as a Map Source in MOBAC

Tags: openstreetmap, mobile-atlas-creator

I am generating custom OSM XML files using JOSM. I now need to add these as a Custom Map Source in MOBAC. Can I do this from the local file or do I need to create a local web server to load them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that MOBAC's just a tile scraper.  There's a big "please don't use it to scrape OSM's map layers" note over at the [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mobile_Atlas_Creator).

I'd expect that you could as you suggest [set up your own tile server](https://switch2osm.org/manually-building-a-tile-server-16-04-2-lts/) and point it at that.

Comment: Thank you very much. The link your provided looks like a good solution.

Comment: If you have a small area to cover, you might as well use maperitive to apply a map style (which the XML file does not have) and create map tiles.